# C# Game Server with SQL Server database error

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I have a game server. It's written in C# with SQL Server 2005. The server is doing fine for about an hour or so, but then something happens, a database error. I am not too much into C#, so I am not sure what is the error and what's causing it. Here's the console output:

[image]

#### Update:

Alright, trying to follow Paparazzi 's "simple instructions" ...
I have modified the code like so:

```
public virtual StoredProcRet StoredProc(string Procedure, params SqlParameter[] Params)
{
    SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

    DataSet Results;
    int RETURN_VALUE;

    try
    {
        Connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            Command.Connection = Connection;
            Command.CommandText = Procedure;
            Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (Params != null)
            {
                foreach (SqlParameter p in Params)
                    {
                        Command.Parameters.Add(p);
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                return new StoredProcRet(-1, null);
            }

            SqlParameter param = Command.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int);
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

            Results = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = Command;
            adapter.Fill(Results);

            int FINAL_VALUE;
            int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Command.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value), out FINAL_VALUE);
            RETURN_VALUE = FINAL_VALUE;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return new StoredProcRet(-1, null);
    }
    finally
    {
        Connection.Close();
    }

    return new StoredProcRet(RETURN_VALUE, Results);
}
```

There current error that I am dealing with (full stack trace and message):

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolea
n breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception
, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObj
ect stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand
 cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler,
TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, Run
Behavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean for
DescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBe
havior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 time
out, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean
describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehav
ior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletio
nSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asy
ncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehav
ior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, S
tring method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behav
ior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandB
ehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[]
 datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand co
mmand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord,
Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)

   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
   at XiasporaServer.SQLDatabase.StoredProc(String Procedure, SqlParameter[] Par
ams)
Procedure or Function 'UpdatePlayer' expects parameter '@LoginID', which was not
 supplied.
```

UpdatePlayer function:

```
public void UpdatePlayer(Player p)
{

    var sLoginID = new SqlParameter("@LoginID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sPlayerName = new SqlParameter("@PlayerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sPassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sEmail = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sIP = new SqlParameter("@IP", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

    var sHomePlanet = new SqlParameter("@HomePlanet", SqlDbType.Int);
    var sCurrentPlanet = new SqlParameter("@CurrentPlanet", SqlDbType.Int);
    var sMoney = new SqlParameter("@Money", SqlDbType.BigInt);
    var sExperiencePoint = new SqlParameter("@ExperiencePoint", SqlDbType.Int);
    var sCurrentShip = new SqlParameter("@CurrentShip", SqlDbType.Int);

    var sBluePrint1 = new SqlParameter("@BluePrint1", SqlDbType.TinyInt);
    var sBluePrint2 = new SqlParameter("@BluePrint2", SqlDbType.TinyInt);
    var sBluePrint3 = new SqlParameter("@BluePrint3", SqlDbType.TinyInt);
    var sBluePrint4 = new SqlParameter("@BluePrint4", SqlDbType.TinyInt);
    var sBluePrint5 = new SqlParameter("@BluePrint5", SqlDbType.TinyInt);
    var sBluePrint6 = new SqlParameter("@BluePrint6", SqlDbType.TinyInt);
    var sBluePrint7 = new SqlParameter("@BluePrint7", SqlDbType.TinyInt);
    var sBluePrint8 = new SqlParameter("@BluePrint8", SqlDbType.TinyInt);

    var sShip1 = new SqlParameter("@Ship1", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sShip2 = new SqlParameter("@Ship2", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sShip3 = new SqlParameter("@Ship3", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sShip4 = new SqlParameter("@Ship4", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sShip5 = new SqlParameter("@Ship5", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

    var sShipMisc1 = new SqlParameter("@ShipMisc1", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sShipMisc2 = new SqlParameter("@ShipMisc2", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sShipMisc3 = new SqlParameter("@ShipMisc3", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sShipMisc4 = new SqlParameter("@ShipMisc4", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sShipMisc5 = new SqlParameter("@ShipMisc5", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

    var sGuild = new SqlParameter("@Guild", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sGuildRank = new SqlParameter("@GuildRank", SqlDbType.Int);
    var sGuildCredit = new SqlParameter("@GuildCredit", SqlDbType.BigInt);

    var sGenKill = new SqlParameter("@GenKill", SqlDbType.Int);
    var sVelicKill = new SqlParameter("@VelicKill", SqlDbType.Int);
    var sGenVelicAlignment = new SqlParameter("@GenVelicAlignment", SqlDbType.Int);
    var sBonusDamage = new SqlParameter("@BonusDamage", SqlDbType.Int);
    var sUserRef = new SqlParameter("@UserRef", SqlDbType.Int);

    sLoginID.Value = p.LoginID;
    sPlayerName.Value = p.PlayerName;
    sPassword.Value = p.Password;
    sEmail.Value = p.Email;
    sIP.Value = p.IP;
    
    sHomePlanet.Value = p.HomePlanet;
    sCurrentPlanet.Value = p.CurrentPlanet;
    sMoney.Value = p.Money;
    sExperiencePoint.Value = p.ExperiencePoint;
    sCurrentShip.Value = p.CurrentShip;
    
    sBluePrint1.Value = p.BluePrint1;
    sBluePrint2.Value = p.BluePrint2;
    sBluePrint3.Value = p.BluePrint3;
    sBluePrint4.Value = p.BluePrint4;
    sBluePrint5.Value = p.BluePrint5;
    sBluePrint6.Value = p.BluePrint6;
    sBluePrint7.Value = p.BluePrint7;
    sBluePrint8.Value = p.BluePrint8;
    
    sShip1.Value = p.Ship1;
    sShip2.Value = p.Ship2;
    sShip3.Value = p.Ship3;
    sShip4.Value = p.Ship4;
    sShip5.Value = p.Ship5;
    
    sShipMisc1.Value = p.ShipMisc1;
    sShipMisc2.Value = p.ShipMisc2;
    sShipMisc3.Value = p.ShipMisc3;
    sShipMisc4.Value = p.ShipMisc4;
    sShipMisc5.Value = p.ShipMisc5;
    
    sGuild.Value = p.Guild;
    sGuildRank.Value = p.GuildRank;
    sGuildCredit.Value = p.GuildCredit;
    
    sGenKill.Value = p.GenKill;
    sVelicKill.Value = p.VelicKill;
    sGenVelicAlignment.Value = p.GenVelicAlignment;
    sBonusDamage.Value = p.BonusDamage;
    sUserRef.Value = p.UserRef;

            StoredProc("UpdatePlayer",
                sLoginID, sPlayerName, sPassword, sEmail, sIP, sHomePlanet,
                sCurrentPlanet, sMoney, sExperiencePoint, sCurrentShip,
                sBluePrint1, sBluePrint2, sBluePrint3, sBluePrint4, sBluePrint5, sBluePrint6, sBluePrint7, sBluePrint8,
                sShip1, sShip2, sShip3, sShip4, sShip5,
                sShipMisc1, sShipMisc2, sShipMisc3, sShipMisc4, sShipMisc5,
                sGuild, sGuildRank, sGuildCredit, sGenKill, sVelicKill, sGenVelicAlignment, sBonusDamage, sUserRef);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is the exact error message? The stacktrace tells us where the error occurs but we need to know what is the exact error (ex.Message)

Comment: that was like SQL connection error. have you checked the connectionstring!

Comment: Agree with @Steve.  Post the top of the call stack, please.

Comment: Also, post the entire stack trace as text instead of as an image.

Comment: I will do that and post the result later, thanks.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I would rather see a `try catch finally` where you close the connection in the `finally`.

I would rather see the command in a `using` block.

```
try
{
    Connection.Open();
    using (Command cmd = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    return new StoredProcRet(-1, null);
}
finally 
{
    Connection.Close();
}
```

As for the cause of the error I am not sure.

Comment: Messed up.  I gave you some simple instructions.

Comment: Can you please show me what have I messed up ? I am kinda newbie in this whole MSSQL stuff. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect error could be in following code:

```
   try
   {
        Results = new DataSet();
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter {SelectCommand = Command};
        adapter.Fill(Results);
        Connection.Close();

        RETURN_VALUE = Convert.ToInt32(Command.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value);
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
```

**Why?**

1. If the `SqlException` hjappens before `Connection.Close()`, program fails to `catch` and the connection will remain open, so after some time you will have connection pool issues
2. You are only catching `SqlException`, if error happens while parsing `Convert.ToInt32`, then `SqlException` is not thrown, but `InvalidCast` or `OverflowException` could be thrown. In this case your program will terminate with an uncaught exception

**What to fix?**

1. Use `try ... catch ... finally` to make sure connection is always closed in `finally` block
2. Use `Int32.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: I am using your suggestion combined with Paparazzi 's code and will see what will happen and post any results later on.

Comment: Surely yes. But this is one area from your code. If it still fails you can put entire error stack trace in your question and some more code like StoredProcedure etc.

Comment: The error says @LoginId parameter is not sent to stored procedure. Thats the error

Comment: Do you have any idea what can be the cause ?

Comment: This error usually comes when a parameter is not passed, but I can see that its present in your case. Its pretty strange. Maybe the executing code is different than debugging code. Try fresh complied code.@BernardDanken

Comment: I know it's present and that's why I am banging my head about "what the ....... is happening ??". The executing code is same. Also, it will check for any nulls before actually adding the Params. Check SQLDatabase.cs code again, am I doing everything right in that StoredProcRet ?

I tried to debug RETURN_VALUE and Results like so: Console.WriteLine(RETURN_VALUE); Console.WriteLine(Results);

Comment: You can specifically add code just before the Params for loop to see whether it contains the parameter LoginID or not. If not then write entire params to disk and if possible write call stack to see who is calling it without parameters. Is there any other method too calling same stored procedure? @BernardDanken

Comment: I think I found what the problem is ! There are some people that has symbols in their LoginID's. For example (FOXY@, Stra/L, ettka;", JUST* and so on). Can these symbols break the StoredProc ?

Comment: I dont think that will break your procedure. @BernardDanken

Comment: So what if I dont update LoginID at all ? LoginID is constant just like Email. Email is never updated in StoredProc and it's the same as LoginID ? It can't be changed, so it probably can work without updating it ?

Comment: You can try that. If its not changing and your procedure dont require it in where clause. There are slight chance that your code then might give ertor in next parameter. But try that @BernardDanken

Comment: Well that won't work it's required and can't be removed.